# Nginx custom 404 page results in 500 internal server error

Tags: nginx

Here is my nginx config:

```
 server {

    # Running port
    listen 80;

    error_page 404 /404;

    # Settings to by-pass for static files
    location ^~ / {

        # Example:
        # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
        root /var/www;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
    }

    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
     }

    location @htmlext {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    }
}
```

The intention is to show the page `/404` when a 404 error occurs.  However, I'm now getting a `500 Internal Server Error` when I visit a nonexistent page.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is here : `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;` and the use of the `last` flag.

Here is [what the doc says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) :

> If these directives [rewrite] are put inside location, the `last` flag
>   should be replaced by `break`, or otherwise nginx will make 10 cycles
>   and return the 500 error

This is what we can see in the Logs. Here i've asked for `fake.html` which does not exists :

```
[debug] 3480#0: *1 http script var: "/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html"
[debug] 3480#0: *1 trying to use file: "/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html" "/var/www/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html"
[debug] 3480#0: *1 http script var: "/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html"
[debug] 3480#0: *1 trying to use dir: "/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html" "/var/www/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html"
[debug] 3480#0: *1 trying to use file: "@htmlext" "/var/www@htmlext"
[error] 3480#0: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named location "@htmlext"....
[debug] 3480#0: *1 http finalize request: 500, "/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html?" a:1, c:7
[debug] 3480#0: *1 http special response: 500, "/fake.html.html.html.html.html.html?"
```

Interesting ! ;)

So, replace your rewrite rule by : `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html break;`

Alternatively, you can return a `404` if none of the file exists in the `try_files` directive :

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext =404;
```

---

However, at this point, your custom `404` page should not work.

Here's what i suggest :

```
server {
    # Running port
    listen 80;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~^/404.html {
       root /var/www;
       internal;
    }

    # Your other stuff Here ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
try_files $uri = 404;
```

with:

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to define 404 page:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location  /404.html {
    internal;
}
```